# Recommendation of Book about Linear Programming and Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, linear-programming

I'm going to take this course next semester

> **Description** Formulation, solution and applications of integer programs. Branch and bound, cutting plane, and column generation algorithms. Combinatorial optimization. Stochastic Optimization. A large emphasis will be placed on modelling. Students will select and present a case study of an application of integer programming in an area of their choice.
>
> **Prerequisite**  a course in linear algebra and a good knowledge of linear programming

I studied linear algebra and linear programming many years ago so I've completely forgotten everything.  But I really want to take this course, (there aren't many choices anyway).  Therefore I will make some preparation.

Can you recommend some concise introduction books on these 2 topics?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20643)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look, it's related topic [Linear Programming Book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20643/linear-programming-books).

In my opinion if you need just concise review it will be helpful [An Introduction to Linear Programming](http://web.williams.edu/go/math/sjmiller/public_html/399/handouts/LinearProgramming.pdf). Great book with no so complicated proofs and explanations [Deterministic Operations Research](http://books.google.com/books/about/Deterministic_Operations_Research.html?id=VqjhIZhsITsC&redir_esc=y). And the last one, book on very advanced level [Linear Programming and Network Flows](http://books.google.com/books?id=2DKKHvV_xVwC&dq=bazaraa&source=gbs_similarbooks&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to refresh your knowledge with the video lectures of [Stephen Boyd](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/videos.html) who is the coauthor of [the famous (and free!) book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/).